# exp() overflow error python 3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, exp, overflowexception

I tried various solutions for below, but I still get the errors as described:

```
log1p(1 + math.exp(comp * -1))
```

Error: `OverflowError: math range error`

So I changed it to: `log1p(1 + np.exp(comp * -1))`
Now I get error : `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp`

So again based on some suggestion on previous questions asked I changed it to:           `log1p(1 + np.exp((comp * -1), dtype=np.float256))`

Now my error is : `module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float256'`

Any other suggestions? Please help thanks!

**EDIT:**
X -> Input feature array of 'N' rows and 'm' features.
w -> weight vector of size 'm'

```
    for rowIndex in range(len(X)):
        val1 = np.sum(np.dot(X[rowIndex], w))
        val2 = y[rowIndex]
        comp = np.dot(val2, val1)
        loss = loss + log1p(1 + np.exp((comp * -1)))
```

Comment: What is the value of `comp`? Also, what you are attempting to compute is `ln(2 + exp(-comp))`. Is this really what you want?

Comment: 'comp' is just some value which could go upto 6000 in some cases... 'log1p(1 + math.exp(comp * -1))' is what I want to do...

Comment: Do you realise that `log1p(x) = log(x + 1)`? Also, `log1p(1 + math.exp(comp * -1))` works fine for various values of `comp`, including `6000`. Please provide a complete example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I note that already for `comp` = 40, the `exp` part can be treated as zero: `log1p(1+exp(-40))-log(2)` is zero.

Comment: Can `comp` be negative? What you describe doesn't seem possible otherwise. And if `comp` is large and negative, then the `1 +  ...` will be insignificant, so your expression `log1p(1 + math.exp(comp * -1))` will be simply `-comp`, to within numerical error. (Also: what @jmd_dk said: are you _sure_ you want `log(1 + 1 + math.exp(...))`?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the code as below:

```
loss = loss - log1p(expit(val))
```

Basically I rearranged my code to be able to use the expit function...

Comment: That doesn't look like the same thing at all. Note that it's _not_ true that `log1p(thing) = -log1p(1/thing)`. Are you _sure_ you mean `log1p` and not `log`?